# publishing asp.net correctly but project is appear without styles on server version

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-manager

I am working with asp.net webforms project. I have published my project on iis . I  checked project link on server with browser .  pages are looking  without styles. On iis manager, I have put my project on application pool with these properties :
32 bit application :true
Integrated
And i have checked if css files is exist.
What the missing things that i have to do.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could start by seeing where the browser is looking for the CSS files, and figure out if that's actually where they are, and if not why not.

Comment: Thank you for replay,i found solution Wich is work correctly. The solution was to enable http static content MIME  mapping on server in windows add and remove features in www section.

Comment: You can add that as a solution below (in an Answer) and select it as correct in order to close out this question.